# Windows server 2008 update battery died now laptop won't boot

Tags: boot, laptop, battery, windows-server-2008

I have run into a snag and cannot for the life of me figure out the solution and was hoping someone here may have an idea as to what I can do.

I installed server 2008 standard on an old laptop (Fujitso Siemens Amilo Pro V3515). All went well, configuring etc, and then I did windows update. After downloading all the necessary files the laptop continued to install them. As it was busy with .net3.5 at the time I had to leave but I checked that the laptop cable was plugged in etc. When I came back the laptop was dead (plug was never switched ON - can so damn nigh kick myself in the goonies for this!) and when I started it up, all I got was a black screen and fans running. Just to clarify, the screen comes on, but stays dull black. 
This laptop does NOT have a dvd drive and I installed via USB, but now I cannot seem to get into any repair mode or boot options or anything. When I restart (via power button as its the only way) and press whatever (F2, F8 or F12) nothing happens and the laptop just does its thing and fans are running and screen black.

Is there a way to get into the repair console/environment as I said I have no disk drive so inserting dvd and repair from there is not an option. My only option seems to be via USB but am not sure how to go about that and am very close to chucking this nefarious machine out the window.

If all else fails, is there an option to completely wipe this thing as I am getting desperate now I will just as much rather reload server 2008 from scratch just to get this thing working again.

Any advice will be very very very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect it from the power in the wall, remove the battery and then press the power-on button for a few seconds.
Reconnect it to power and try to boot it WITHOUT battery.
It will probably be back to normal after that. (But you may have to revert to a restore point because of the shutdown while installing updates.)

The startup without battery clears some internal logic that prevents normal bootup.
This is a known trick for various models and brands of laptops after they have suffered a full battery drain.

Comment: Thanks for the info but this thing is still the same - I tried your suggestion 5 times just to be sure. Screen remains black, fans are on, disk light is on/flickering, and hdd is working. I've had to deal with many many issues but this one is a first.

Comment: That is not good.... If the screen remains black but the HD lights flicker it almost looks as if the LCD panel itself it broken. Have tried to attach an external monitor ? Chances are that external display is OK.

Comment: I haven't connected an external monitor just yet - will only be able to on Saturday and if I dont get this right I will attempt that and see what happens. Weird because before the updates and during the lcd was working perfectly. All this because of a bloody switch that was not flicked....

Comment: Frustration got the better of me so went out and gotten hold of a monitor, hooked it up and screen still black........
Btw, I am in another town and will be home (in the sticks) again Saturday hence I couldn't find a monitor right away. Any other ideas as to what to try?

Comment: @Raxephion I'm sorry to day this, but this starts to sound more and more like hardware damage. Specifically the GPU coming loose from the motherboard. Check this YouTube video for possible fix (it may work, or not). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxhkqAE2D9o

Comment: Thanks for the link - watching it right now and going to try something. Gosh I hope this can come right. Will keep you posted!

Comment: Finally solved! Just thought to check in and relay the outcome - the inverter was blown. Fit a new one (well second-hand) and whala-Bob's your Uncle! Somehow between when the battery died whilst udating and me powering on again the inverter blew.

Comment: @Raxephion Thanks for the feedback... Inverter taking off like that is really weird. I can't recall having encountered that one before and I've been in the IT business for over 30 years. Guess there is a 1st for everything...